# Updating array in MongoDb using Node is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've definitely have done my due diligence, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

I have a collection in Mongo (trips) with the following:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56f5ee3dab124b181256ddf1"),
    "waypoints": [{
        "address": "",
        "sequenceNumber": 0
    }]
}
```

To update waypoint.address, I have done the following:

```
var tripId = new mongodb.ObjectID(waypoint.tripId);
    var db = resources.GetDbConn();
    db.collection('trips').update(
        { _id: tripId,
          'waypoints.sequenceNumber': waypoint.sequenceNumber
        },
        {$set: 
            { 'waypoints.$.address': waypoint.address}
        });
```

However, this is not working. Am I missing, or not understanding something?

UPDATE:

I finally figured this out. 'waypoint.sequenceNumber' was being stored as an integer, however, I was querying this as a string. Ugh. Shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is to do with the _id field being an ObjectID(1), and not just the literal integer 1.

Comment: Looking at the [question revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36238239/revisions) it was misleading. For future reference people seem to often obfuscate `ObjectId` values in posts ( i guess they "think" it's a security issue ) and values like `ObjectId("1")` which would simply throw an error should be ignored. The OP realized there real mistake anyway.